# Multiple calls wait on the same async task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-runtime, task, .net-4.5

Basically I have a lot of places in my app where in order to do something I need to make sure a product image is downloaded. I want to centralize this call into one place so I make sure to only download it once. I'm trying to do like this in my class:

```
private IAsyncOperation<bool> _downloadCoverTask;

internal IAsyncOperation<bool> DownloadCoverAsync()
{
    if (this._downloadCoverTask == null)
    {
        this._downloadCoverTask = this._cloudProduct.Image.DownloadAsync();
    }

    return this._downloadCoverTask;
}
```

_cloudProduct.Image.DownloadAsync() is a method which actually does the image downloading (it also happens to be in a library that I don't control).

So in my code where I need to download the image, I do

```
await product.DownloadCoverAsync();
// do stuff with the image
```

This works ok the first time I call it, but the second time it's called I get the exception "A delegate was assigned when not allowed." I don't get any stack trace or anything either.

This would get called a bunch of places, but I'm hoping that they would all wait on the same task, and then continue when it's complete. If it's already completed I hope it would just return right away. It's possible that I'm misunderstanding and that's just not how it works?

(Yes, I posted this [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332790/), but wasn't able to get an answer and I think this question summarizes the issue better. There is also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557009/), but that uses TPL and seems to have a much more complex goal.)

Comment: For `Task<T>` I'm sure you'd be okay... looks like this is a WinRT-specific problem :(

Comment: I was about to post the same answer that I gave to your other question. Could you describe why it didn't work?

Comment: For posterity - one place where this error can also show is when in C++ you call `create_task` on one `IAsyncOperation` twice. It's better to cache tasks than IAsyncOperations in C++ as well.

Comment: This also happens in C++/WinRT when `co_await`'ing the same async operation twice. unfortunately there isn't an easy workaround here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a `Task<bool>` instead of  an `IAsyncOperation<bool>`. You can get a task using the [`AsTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779752.aspx) extension method.